# Python Pandas dataframe reading exact specified range in an excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a lot of different table (and other unstructured data in an excel sheet) .. I need to create a dataframe out of range 'A3:D20' from 'Sheet2' of Excel sheet 'data'.

All examples that I come across drilldown up to sheet level, but not how to pick it from an exact range.

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
range = ['A3':'D20']   #<-- how to specify this?
spots = pd.DataFrame(sheet.range) #what should be the exact syntax for this?

print (spots)
```

Once I get this, I plan to look up data in column A and find its corresponding value in column B.

Edit 1: I realised that openpyxl takes too long, and so have changed that to `pandas.read_excel('data.xlsx','Sheet2')` instead, and it is much faster at that stage at least.

Edit 2: For the time being, I have put my data in just one sheet and:

- removed all other info
- added column names,
- applied `index_col` on my leftmost column
- then used `wb.loc[]`

Comment: I would say this is an option that would come in very handy when pandas has to read a specified range of cells. This may be the case for corporate spreadsheets that contain unnecessary information or metadata or other kind of stuff that does not need to end up in the data analysis pipeline. I would want the pandas community to include this `range=[]` argument.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/) module.

Here's an example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='data.xlsx', 
                   read_only=True)

ws = wb['Sheet2']

# Read the cell values into a list of lists
data_rows = []
for row in ws['A3':'D20']:
    data_cols = []
    for cell in row:
        data_cols.append(cell.value)
    data_rows.append(data_cols)

# Transform into dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
```

Comment: thanks vm - looks like that will be the way to do.. but seems such a long-wound way to do this.. oh well.. thanks again!

Answer (score 40):

Use the following arguments from [pandas read_excel documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> - skiprows : list-like
>
>   - Rows to skip at the beginning (0-indexed)
> - nrows: int, default None
>
>   - Number of rows to parse.
> - parse_cols : int or list, default None
>
>   - If None then parse all columns,
>   - If int then indicates last column to be parsed
>   - If list of ints then indicates list of column numbers to be parsed
>   - If string then indicates comma separated list of column names and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”)

I imagine the call will look like:

```
df = read_excel(filename, 'Sheet2', skiprows = 2, nrows=18,  parse_cols = 'A:D')
```

## EDIT:

in later version of pandas `parse_cols` has been renamed to `usecols` so the above call should be rewritten as:

```
df = read_excel(filename, 'Sheet2', skiprows = 2, nrows=18,  usecols= 'A:D')
```

Comment: thanks vm for your reply.. I thought about the same, using 'parse_cols' .. but what if there is data below rows 20 which I don't want to be used for this?

Comment: @Dark Matter I want an exact part of the excel sheet (workbook.worksheet.range) as a dataframe to lookup within.. read_excel seems to only have remove rows and apply which columns to look at.. but that means all rows of that column (except the skipped rows at the top) will get selected

Comment: Then why dont you transpose the dataframe and again select whatever you want

Comment: Since version 0.23.0 `pandas.read_excel` has an `nrows` parameter, that specifies the number of rows to parse. Between that and `parse_cols` one should be able to specify a contiguous range.

Comment: `parse_cols` is now `usecols`

Answer (score 20):

my answer with pandas O.25 tested and worked well

```py
pd.read_excel('resultat-elections-2012.xls', sheet_name = 'France entière T1T2', skiprows = 2,  nrows= 5, usecols = 'A:H')
pd.read_excel('resultat-elections-2012.xls', index_col = None, skiprows= 2, nrows= 5, sheet_name='France entière T1T2', usecols=range(0,8))
```

So :
i need data after two first lines ; selected desired lines (5) and col A to H.
Be carefull @shane answer's need to be improved and updated with the new parameters of Pandas

[image: my original excel]

[image: my process with pandas read_excel]

Answer (score 5):

One option is to write a simple function converting the range into the arguments needed in the `pd.read_excel` function.

This is fairly straight forward and saves you the hassle of working out how many rows to skip and the number of rows to use when you have many tables you want to read.

I'm sure the below code can be refined. But you get the gist of it.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string


def convert_range(excel_range):
    """ Converts a range (i.e. something like 'A3:D20') and returns
    the corresponding arguments to use in pd.read_excel."""

    # Get cell addresses from range (i.e. A3 and D20)
    upper_left, lower_right = excel_range.split(':')

    # Convert cell address ('A3') to col (A) and row (3)
    left_col, top_row = coordinate_from_string(upper_left)
    right_col, bottom_row = coordinate_from_string(lower_right)

    return {'usecols': f'{left_col}:{right_col}',
            'skiprows': int(top_row) - 1,
            'nrows': int(bottom_row) - int(top_row) + 1}


# Sample usage
excel_range = 'A3:D20'
sheet_name = 'your_sheet'
file_path = r'C:/some_excel.xlsx'

# Get the rest of the args using the custom function
args = convert_range(excel_range)

df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, **args)
```