# draw line/scatter plot from specific cells in an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I have an excel file with my data in sheet named 'main'.

I want to plot a line plot (or scatter) for particular cells in the 'main' sheet

The data I want to use in 'main' is:

X-axis data is in column A i.e. from A36 to A136
and
Y-axis data is in column A i.e. from G36 to G136

Here is the code I used to make the simpler version of the plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_excel('ob_half_cd100_titration.xlsx', 'test', parse_cols='A')
y = pd.read_excel('ob_half_cd100_titration.xlsx', 'test', parse_cols='B')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The final figure should look like the following image (made from the 'test' sheet):
[image]

Link to the excel file :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pq4pzq7y7ng29e/ob_half_cd100_titration.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: See documentation https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: Try removing the import pylab as plt line

Comment: The question lacks a problem description. What is the problem? What do you get when running the code? Is there an error thrown? In how far is the output different from what you expect?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the problem is I do not have a code for specifying cells in excel sheet, hence the issue. I can plot column A and column B but I want to make plot with specific cells in column A and column B.

Comment: Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38561536/7390366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a slice of the data:

```
plt.plot(x[35:136], y[35:136])
```