# autodetecting table properly from excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have several tables, each structured its own way. Table may start at Cell(C6) or something of this kind. Some of them horizontal, some vertical. I want to extract table data into `pandas` dataframe. Now I achieve it by defining first column header and trimming out everything before.  Is there any proper and universal way of doing it?

in:[image: in]

out:[image: out]

Comment: There is _no_ universal way of handling unstructured data, I think your current approach is fine.

Comment: I think it mach more easy way to use VBA to prepare your files. Look at the Range("B4").CurrentRegion property. It can select a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your file into .csv format in excel, you can use this to skip the initial space:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('directory/filename.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Then you can use your desired columns and rows among your cells.

Comment: but they're not empty at all. as shown in picture, there might be 'something' out of table

Comment: Ok, I see, you want to choose a part by specifying a specific range, correct?

Comment: Check this link, it might help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560748/python-pandas-dataframe-reading-exact-specified-range-in-an-excel-sheet)

Comment: unfortunately, that solution is too obvious

Comment: i want to detect table on sheet, excluding some single data cells