# Read Data from multiple Excel Files and normalize the data into Arrays

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Lets say I have 3 different Excel File (file1.xlsx, file2.xlsx, file3.xlsx)  with this data:

- 1.4
- 1.3
- 1.42
- 1.3

---

- 1.4
- 1.33
- 1.4
- 1.13

---

- 1.4
- 1.23
- 1.14
- 1.3

I want to write the normalized values into an Array in python. Is there a way to combine the pd.read_xlsx('file1.xlsx') with normalizing the data to 1? Right now I am reading every file and then normalizing every single one and finally writing it into one array.

```
data1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
data2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')
data3 = pd.read_excel('file3.xlsx')
```

following the normalizing

```
x = np.array([data1,data2,data3])
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
```

I believe there is an easier way, to simply read data from an folder full of excel-files where the designated data is at the same cells. Anybody has an idea how to?

Answer (score 0):

You need processing each file to list of DataFrames in list comprehension, then for expected output use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with transpose:

```
import glob

data = [pd.read_excel(f) for for f in glob.glob(path)]

x = pd.concat(data, axis=1).T.to_numpy()
```

Or your solution:

```
x = np.array(data)
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
```

EDIT:

```
#your solution for read data
data = [pd.read_excel(f, skiprows=14, usecols='C', nrows=30, engine='openpyxl') 
        for f in glob.glob('C:/Users/user/Desktop/JupyterNB/folder/*.xlsx')]
```

Testing solution:

```
#sample data 
data = [pd.DataFrame([0,4,5,9]),
        pd.DataFrame([4,55,9,12]),
        pd.DataFrame([10,104,5,9])]

#normalize each file separately and then join by concat
L = [(x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x)) for x in data]
out = pd.concat(L, axis=1).T.to_numpy()
print (out)
[[0.         0.44444444 0.55555556 1.        ]
 [0.         1.         0.09803922 0.15686275]
 [0.05050505 1.         0.         0.04040404]]

#first concat and then normalize
x = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
out = ((x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x))).T.to_numpy()
print (out) 
[[0.         0.44444444 0.55555556 1.        ]
 [0.         1.         0.09803922 0.15686275]
 [0.05050505 1.         0.         0.04040404]]
```

Comment: is there a way to destinate to specific cells from each file? The cells wont change from file to file.

Comment: @Albert - Can you be more specific?

Comment: i want to read data in each file from the range of C44:C56 for example, not the whole filedata. and the glob(path) shows me an permission denied because i give glob the destination folder

Comment: @Albert - so need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38561012/2901002) solution?

Comment: @Albert - `permission denied` - is not possible set input folder?

Comment: yes thank you very much. it is now possible to read single files via path with: `data = [pd.read_excel(f, skiprows=14, usecols='C', nrows=30, engine='openpyxl') for f in glob.glob('C:/Users/user/Desktop/JupyterNB/folder/file.xlsx')]
data = (data-np.min(data))/(np.max(data)-np.min(data))
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1)` but i cant set the path to 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/JupyterNB/folder/*' to read all files at once

Comment: @Albert - You are close, change `glob.glob('C:/Users/user/Desktop/JupyterNB/folder/file.xlsx')` to `glob.glob('C:/Users/user/Desktop/JupyterNB/folder/*.xlsx')`

Comment: i still get errors: with enginge=openpyxl it is `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` and without it is: `Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.`

Comment: @Albert - One question `engine='openpyxl'` should be removed?

Comment: i tried it with enginge and without engine, it either says pls specify engine, or bad zip file

Comment: ok i found the problem, some files had an dot in its names, so the file type was expected after that and lead to an error (f.e. 'V2.0')